# calculus of variation and second derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, hamilton-equations

Starting from the Hamiltonian system

$$
\dot{z}(t) = H(t,z(t))
$$

we deduce the variational system

$$
\dot{\delta z} = dH(t,z(t)).\delta z
$$

$\delta z$ means we consider curves close to $z(t)$ for a certain topology. 
Is there a sense to consider the equation for $\ddot{z}(t)$ and how is it related to the variational system ?

Thanks !

Comment: When you ask "is there a sense" what exactly do you mean? I'm not sure if this has a clear meaning in physics, but at least in the other two topics you have tagged, its not clear to me what you mean when you ask that.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas ok yeah some examples where it appears, where do we find these equation for $\ddot{z}$